# mongodb created by Docker-compose, doesn't create initial db?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: devuser
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: devuser
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: devDB
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    volumes:
        - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

mongo-init.js

```
 db.createUser(
    {
        user: "devuser",
        pwd: "devuser",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "devDB"
            }
        ]
    }
 );
use devDB;
db.item.insert(
 [
   {
     "id": "xsd4cv89t5f5um4b",
     "name": "r44d7piq",
     "price": 1485521573482,
     "dateCreation": 1485521569056
   }  
 ]
```

);

I run it

```
 docker-compose up --build -d mongodb
```

I connect to mongodb

```
mongo -u devuser -p devuser
```

I check dbs:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB   
local   0.000GB
```

Why I don't see the devDB?

It seems to me pretty standard, I've copied the above from several examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is created on demand when an operation that needs it is performed.

You haven't performed any operations, hence there is no database created.

Comment: I've added an insert to the script (see edited question), but nothing is happening...

Comment: I've added also "use devDB" and db.insert.item...but still I don't see anything

Comment: Is the script being run?

Comment: good question...I don't see it running in the logs...so why?

Comment: I tried to delete all previous containers and mount a data volume. it seems the user is created but not the db. Don't understand why